# Get sharing status of content in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to share content in Android, so I use following code for sharing:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(
  android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
  sharingIntent, "Share using"), 1000);
```

In `onActivityResult()`, I write following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Log.d("TAG", "::onActivityResult:" + "requestCode:" + requestCode
    + "resultCode:" + resultCode + "Data:" + data);
}
```

When `onActivityResult()` is called, `resultCode` is always `0`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `ACTION_SEND` is not set up for use with `startActivityForResult()`. No implementer of `ACTION_SEND` needs to call `setResult()`, and therefore few, if any, will.

[Any `Intent` action whose documentation says "Output: nothing"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`.